# Get "Remote Address" (IP address) in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am developing a Chrome extension in which I want to get the IP address for each server request that goes from a client in Chrome. For example, see this image:

[image: developer tools screenshot]

Is there any Chrome Extension javascript API which I can use which will give me this kind of data?

Comment: @lolol That question is about getting the client address, this question is about getting the server address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do this using the webReqest API!

manifest.json

```
...
"permissions": ["webRequest", "*://*/*"]
...
```

background.js

```
chrome.webRequest.onResponseStarted.addListener(
    ({ip}) => console.log(`Network request with ${ip}!`),
    {urls: ['*://*/*']});
```